# How do i interface my prototype and export the result on to the prototype?

Tags: arduino-uno, anylogic

I am building a prototype and conducting my tests by simulating the situations on AnyLogic. My prototype is arduino based, written on c programming. I want the outputs on AnyLogic to be exported onto the prototype, and display the results.

Can I export from AnyLogic to arduino, in C??

Answer (score 0):

If you find a Java library that can do that: yes you can :-)

If not, you can always output to a stupid csv or txt and let your C program read that in...